# C# - Converting string data to actual string representation

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a device that sends out string data representing its settings, but the data is encoded in the string as its unicode(?) representation. For example, the device sends the string "00530079007300740065006D" which represents the string "System". Are there function built into C# that will convert the string data sent from the device to the actual string? If not, can someone advise me on how best to perform this conversion?

Comment: There is likely a built in function, but without knowing the means of encoding "System" to that string its hard to give you a definate solution.

Comment: In answer to my own comment above. Its definately Hex.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a built-in function, but it is only one line of code:

```
string input = "00530079007300740065006D";

String output = new String(Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length/4)
     .Select(idx => (char)int.Parse(input.Substring(idx *  4,4),
           NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray());
```

Here's another one, which is perhaps a little more high-minded in not doing the hacky char/int cast:

```
string out2 =
   Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length/2)
     .Select(idx => byte.Parse(input.Substring(idx * 2, 2),
          NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray());
```

Comment: I was thinking it looked like hex, but your solution throws an OverflowException on the parsing to Int32.

Comment: Both my solutions have been run in Linqpad before I posted them - not sure what's happened in translation...

Comment: Your Substring should be `input.Substring(idx *4,4)`, Surely? Otherwise it'll get the rest of the string after your start index. You only want 4 chars per int

Comment: Thanks Jamiec!  That got lost while I was reformatting the line breaks into StackOverflow.  I can see now why it wouldn't have worked for you...

Comment: This is far more complex and tricky than the built in methods which handle the various encodings for you..

Comment: Will, thanks for th input. These two methods give me the exact output I was looking for.

Comment: @Jimmy - Can you give an example of the built in methods?

Answer (score 1):

Totally jumping on @Will Dean's solution bandwagon here (so dont mark me as the answer).

If you're using Will's solution alot, I suggest wrapping it into a string extension:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string HexToString(this string input)
    {
        return new String(Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length/4)
                              .Select(idx => (char) int.Parse(input.Substring(idx*4,4),
                                                              NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, .NET has a built in way to move from a given encoding type to another type, say UTF8 -> ASCII or somesuch.  The namespace you'll need is `System.Text.Encoding`.